# Finding word and number of lines in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, console, command

I am trying to find the number of lines that contain the word.  I realize this is possible with the `wc` command and the `-l` flag, but I'm not 100% sure how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wc, you can use grep like this:

```
grep -c "word" file
```

Comment: Is it posible to do this with wc though?

Comment: `grep "word" file | wc -l`?  It's more costly than using just `grep` because it uses two processes.

Comment: wc -l can only count the number of lines/words/characters in the file or stream, but wc by itself can't do any pattern matching or searching.